# Switch documents between libraries on status change - SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, document-library, status

I have three document libraries in a document center and I want all three of them to host documents based on their status.

Lib1 should have the daft documents and once the status is changed from draft to completed it should automatically move to Lib2 and then if status is changed there it should move to Lib3.

Firstly I want to make the status column mandate while uploading the documents. 
How?

Secondly, Is writing a workflow the only possible way to achieve it, if so is there any existing workflow supporting the above operation.

Comment: Why can't you use three views instead of three libraries? Create view and filter by status field.. then add three links to the left navigation which takes user to the respective view

Comment: @AmalHashim Indeed that is a good idea, but I want to set up different permission levels for them as well, so I wanted to go with document libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Create three workflows and attach it to your libraries. Set it to fire when list item was updated. Unfortunately, i don't have sharepoint designer right now and can't screen my workflow. So, i will try to explain logic right in pseudo notation:

```
If Current Item:Status equals StatusTwo
    Copy item in LibraryOne to LibraryTwo
    then Delete item in LibraryOne
```

Where StatusTwo - new status, LibraryOne - old library, LibraryTwo = new location of file. You copy item and then deleted it.

Also you can do this programatically by creating event handlers.